# How do I stop a browser from attempting to parse a JSON response after explicitly setting the 'nosniff' header?

Tags: json, angular, rest, go

I'm currently writing an application that is meant to send out JSON reponses based on a given query. The backend properly sends data to Postman, which leads me to assume it works because there are no errors there. However, when attempting to work with it in the browser, I keep getting the same "Unexpected white space character" error, when I know that it works in postman. I should mention that I'm calling it via this method in Angular:

```
public getCard(): Observable<any> {
 return this.http.get('localhost:4200/card')
```

I've tried setting the response type to 'application/octet-stream' I've tried 'plain/text' and nothing seems to be working. It should just send the data over, and have it display in the console. I plan on dealing with the other issues later, I just want the backend to communicate with my frontend successfully.

I feel like giving up because this has been plaguing me for the last several weeks.

Comment: What does the JSON response in question look like?

Comment: It's from scryfall's bulk data. I can post a piece of sample data where in a couple of hours when I am on my lunch break.

Comment: @jub0bs I figured out it was my implementation. It would send out a JSON payload that wasn't in an array with commas separating the spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
public getCard(): Observable<string> {
  return this.http.get('localhost:4200/card');
}
```

or

```
public getCard(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get('localhost:4200/card', { responseType: 'text' });
}
```

The [angular HttpClient](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient) determines the default content type of the response based on the type of the returned value. So either specify the type of the returned value to `Observable<string>` (for this type, the default `responseType` is `text`) or specify the `responseType` explictly.

Comment: I'll try this when I get home. Thank you for giving me a direction to try.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to give an update on this question. The way my code was implemented, it would create a JSON object, and send it out, then create another and send it out, resulting in the full payload looking like this;

```
{
    ID: 1
}
{
    ID: 2
}
```

As a result, it would be invalid JSON because it isn't in an array. The correct format would be like so:

```
[
    {
        ID: 1
    },
    {
        ID: 2
    }
]
```

So the answer to my question was the implementation. Now that it sends out the array, it is communicating perfectly, but I had to remove my implementation of concurrency until I can figure out how to have an Observer in rxjs handle multiple single piece JSON payloads being send out from the backend since my initial implementation was nearly 100x faster than the 'put everything in an array and send it' approach.